# PHP fetch images stored on database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I manually inserted a image in longblob field named image ...the image is .gif so i entered mimetype as 'image/gif' but it isn't working??

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT image FROM page WHERE number=$ide");

 while($image=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     header('Content-type:'.$image['mimetype']);


    echo $image['image'];
```

Please help it is showig some random binary text instead of the image it also says undefined index mimetype have i done something wrong in defining it ???

Comment: edit-i changed the mimetype to image/gif but the image isnt cropping up still

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the mime type in your SQL query like so:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT image, mimetype FROM page WHERE number=$ide");
```

The mimetype should be `image/gif`

Comment: did that ..the error notice didn't come but the image also didn't show up.the page is blank?@Treffynnon

Comment: Sounds like the image data might have been corrupted when you inserted it into the database. If you [do a `diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) on the data and that of the original image file is it any different?